# Movie about a creature summoned by a Native American curse

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I watched a horror movie about some kind of creature that was brought into the world by a Native American chief casting a curse. I think the creature was a monstrous wolf or a werewolf, but maybe it was some other creature. It could not be killed by conventional weapons. Eventually, a woman somehow figures out that the creature could be killed by a Native American weapon, and doing so would result in the death of the person killing the creature.

The woman sees that someone else is wearing a necklace with a Native American arrowhead on it. She loads the necklace into a shotgun and fires it at the creature. There's a slow motion scene showing the arrowhead flying at the creature and hitting it.

The creature dies, and the woman promptly goes into cardiac arrest. A team of emergency personnel arrives shortly afterwards and revives the woman with a defibrillator.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Monsterwolf* (2010).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535608/?ref_=m_tt_urv):

> A group of people who represent an oil company find new ground to drill for oil but then accidentally unleash a wolf-like creature. The creature wreaks havoc in the town and can only be stopped by the last surviving native American.

And from [this Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1YCNPDGF3LQU5):

> Ok, so the ending was a typical SyFy movie ending. The good guys never die. Its almost like the Hallmark channel. The was to kill the monster was good. **However, the "bone of an enemy" was given to our heroine by her friend, who had the arrowhead on a necklace. At best, it would have been his enemy, not hers. Also, the Native American prophecy was that it took a life to send the angry spirit back.** Ok, fine. However, once destroyed, heroine falls dead, only to be picked up by her love interest and carried her to a waiting ambulance, which was not there 2 minutes ago. **Of course, they revive her.** They should have made the monster come back as she didn't give a life for a life. I get she was technically dead for a minute. When she came back, breaking the prophecy, so should the spirit.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi movie summon native American creature` which returned the IMDb summary above. Subsequent review was found with the Google query `"monsterwolf" necklace`.

Comment: The EMH Mark 1 doesn't quite fit in as a bad guy